# jQuery MP3 player, plugin vs self code

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering how difficult it would be to hand code a jQuery MP3 player vs using a plugin.  All of the plugins I've found so far I'm not to impressed with, but I guess if I had to go with one, I'd go with jPlayer.

I mean just some on click functions for the buttons but I'm not so sure how to actually make the audio files play.

Anyone with knowledge that could turn me in the right direction, please speak up :)

Thanks!

Comment: jPlayer's about the simplest solution for the widest audience at the moment, you could do an HTML5 check first, e.g. `if(document.createElement("audio").play)` use `<audio>`, else use jPlayer as a fallback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Html5 `<audio>` element](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-the-html-5-audio-element/) for new browsers. A little better than a JS control :P.

Comment: Hmm, do you think I could do it with HTML5 alone?  I guess so, huh.  I plan to have buttons like  thishttp://www.marioplanet.com/images/audio_player/pause.png" one which I believe is quite cool ;)  So I could use some CSS buttons with HTML and fall back on something else for older browsers.  Progressive enhancement, I guess!